# What does the union symbol (∪) before the set builder notation mean?

Tags: notation, set-theory

I am reading Robert André's book *Axioms and Set Theory* and, maybe starting at chapter 12, he uses the notation like $\mathbb{N}=\cup\{n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where he puts a union symbol (∪) before the set builder notation. I do not know what it means, though I suspect it is a typo.

Hence, my question: what does $\cup\{x \mid \phi(x)\}$ mean?

Comment: The notation $\mathbb N = \cup \{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ is almost nonsense, and seems unlikely to be written in a math book. I’d like to see a screenshot. I would interpret it to mean that you are taking a union of a single set, which is $\{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$. Of course, that set is just $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @littleO, if you want you check it here: [The book](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf#page=137) or the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1okRZ9jZ05LW329zzOMY2RRVfQkF1asZe/view?usp=sharing). It is the 14th exercise.

Comment: @littleO It is not nonsense in the standard set theory building of the natural numbers, see my answer

Comment: @Alan I think that I am making a more basic point.  If $S$ is a set, and I write $\cup S$, what does that mean? I would think it means that we are taking a union of a single set; but then it is strange to write $\cup S$ rather than simply $S$.

Comment: @littleO  It's lazy abuse of notation to write $\cup x$ instead of $\cup_{x\in I} x$ when the index set is obvious

Comment: Oh, now I think I am starting to understand— as you mentioned, since each natural number is a set, this union is not as pointless as it seemed to me at first.

Comment: @littleO Exactly. I added a second addendum to my answer to explain the abuse of notation

Comment: @Alan: It is not an abuse of notation. It is the notation.

Comment: $\bigcup X=\{y:\exists z\in X\,(y\in z)\}$. And in set theory everything is a set, including any member of $\Bbb N.$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker accepted a bogus answer, as already adequately pointed out by Asaf and David.

Comment: @user21820, the answer does say something wrong, which the author corrects in the comments. I do not see why you would close the question instead of asking me to unaccept the answer or ask the author to change the answer, or even suggest an edit. But I am not putting responsibilities onto you nor saying you should.

Comment: @Schilive: Alan did **not** admit any mistake in the comments, and the last comment ("No, I meant ⋃x, it's the union of all the sets x that are a member of the obvious superset, in this case ℕ") is **plain WRONG**. If you unaccept that answer and accept egreg's instead, I'm fine with it. Otherwise this thread is not worth keeping because it is extremely misleading to all future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is not mysterious and is not “technically wrong” or “abusive” as others commented. You find it in several books; I learned it in the appendix of Kelley's book “General Topology”.

If $A$ is a set, then
$$
\mathop{\cup}A=\{x\mid \exists y\,(y\in A\land x\in y)\}
$$
For instance, if $A=\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$, then $\mathop{\cup}A=\{a,b,c\}$.

<sup>The book you link is not very consistent in notation, I should say.</sup>

In the “almost formal” set theory that's developed in the book, everything is a set. And the natural numbers are defined recursively by
$$
0=\emptyset,\quad n^+=n\cup\{n\}
$$
and collecting what's obtained in this way in the set $\mathbb{N}$. Let's see what happens when the union is applied to $1=\{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
\mathop{\cup}\{n\mid n\in 1\}=0=\emptyset
$$
With $2=\{0,1\}$ we get
$$
\mathop{\cup}\{n\mid n\in 2\}=1
$$
There seems to be a pattern. And indeed there is: if $n$ is a natural number and $y\in n$, then $y\subset n$. Since, by definition,
$$
0\subset 1\subset 2\subset\dotsb
$$
you have that, when $m=k^+$
$$
\mathop{\cup}\{n\mid n\in m\}=k
$$
which you can prove by induction. It follows that
$$
\mathop{\cup}\{n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{N}
$$

---

The notation $\mathop{\cup}A$ is justified by a specific axiom of set theory: the axiom of union states that for any $A$ there exists $B$ such that, for every $x\in B$, there is $y\in A$ with $x\in y$ (probably not the same notation of your book). Using specification, we can isolate from that (possibly big) set the one that we need to use and denote it as shown above.

The “binary union” $A\cup B$ is defined to be $\mathop{\cup}\{A,B\}$.

Answer (score 6):

In a set theory development of the natural numbers,  what we do is we start with nothing but sets and then build structures within that mimic our knowledge of numbers and operations on them.  The standard construction for the natural numbers is to set
$$0:=\emptyset $$
and then inductively define each following natural number by the successor function $s(x)$ which gives the next number after $x$ as
$$s(x+1)=x\cup \{x\}$$

So   $0=\emptyset$  $1=\{0\}=\{\emptyset \}$,  $2=1 \cup \{1\}=\{0\}\cup \{1\}=\{0,1\}$, etc.

Note in this construction the only objects are the empty set and sets built from the empty set,  the numbers are just names we assign to certain configurations of the sets.   In this configuration,  it is true that any natural number is just the set of all the previous numbers

$$n=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$$

### Thus it makes the sense to take the union of the numbers because numbers are just names for special sets.   And when you take the union of all of them, you get all natural numbers.

Added: For your exercise, you just want to show the two sets are equal, so as usual, show they are subsets of each other.  So show any natural number is in that union,  and then show that any member of that union is in fact a natural number

Second addendum:   Technically the author should have written

$$\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb N}x$$
but when the context of the index set is obvious, we often do abuse of notation and skip writing the index set and go straight to
$$\bigcup x$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is a funny concept, that the union of the all the elements of a set is the set itself.

Comment: @Schilive No problem, and yeah,  it's the notion of a "transitive" set.  If this fully answered your question,  go ahead and mark the check box next to it to acceptit

Comment: Technically, $\bigcup_{x\in X} x$ is the abuse of notation. Since $\bigcup$ is a new function symbol that is added as a conservative extension to the language of set theory (under the axioms of Union and Extensionality), using the subscript is an abuse of notation.

Comment: Your last comment sounds like you think that $\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb N}x=\bigcup x$. In fact $\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb N}x=\bigcup\Bbb N$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes,  I was going back and forth in real time, the latter is what I meant

Comment: @AsafKaragila I keep meaning to go back and study some actual formal logic on my own. I only had one grad school course on set theory for foundational stuff and always felt like I was missing out not having taken logic first

Comment: @Alan, could you, please, change $\bigcup x$ to $\bigcup \mathbb{N}$, since I believe that was that you wanted to say? Thank you for the answer either way.

Comment: @Schilive No, I meant $\bigcup x$,  it's the union of all the sets $x$ that are a member of the obvious superset, in this case $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Alan, I do not understand, then, how your answer would answer the question, since you did not mention the notation used in the question text, which was $\cup\mathbb{N}$. I thought it was a mistake because of what you said to David C. Ullrich, and before what the [site](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Union/Set_of_Sets#Definition) said.

Answer (score 1):

It means the union of all such sets which are described by {$x | \phi(x)$}.

Comment: I think this Does Not make Sense because all These Sets are Equal.

Comment: Unless you're trying to define $\mathbb{N}$ as $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \{ n \}$, there is nothing wrong with it appearing on both sides of the equal sign.

Comment: @nomen what do you mean both side of the equal sign? There is no equal sign in my answer

Comment: @insipidintegrator: i mean the left side and the right side.  I agree with you, I am gently replying to miracle173, who is wrong.

Comment: insipidintegrator (If I said this correctly), thank you for the answer. Though I do think FShrike's answer is better, we all want everyone to try to contribute. So, please, if you want to contribute, do it!

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is undefined (I think) as you need to state what $x$ ranges over (context dependent). But Robert is not making a typo. You might recognise it more if I rewrite it like this:

$$\Bbb N=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{n\}$$

Which is true of all sets. $\cup$ just means union, and sometimes people don’t put [the set or property which indexes the union] on the bottom, but rather to the side, as Robert has done. That’s what “$| \phi(x)$” means: the union is taken over those sets $x$ such that $\phi(x)$. It would be equivalent (provided you had a background from where $x$ will come, like a universe or some other set $A$) to write: $$\cup\{x\in A:\phi(x)\}=\bigcup_{x\in A:\phi(x)}\{x\}$$

Comment: In this case since it is a set theory book, they are probably defining each natural number as the set of all previous numbers, with $0=\emptyset$.  In which case, it is actually true that the natural numbers is the union of the numbers themselves, not the singleton sets (though that's also true,  just trivial)

Comment: The set $S = \{ x \in A \mid \phi(x) \}$ is one particular set. Writing $\cup  \{ x \in A \mid \phi(x) \}$ should be equivalent to writing $\cup S$, which is a strange thing to write because we are taking the union of a single set $S$. We might as well just write $S$ instead of $\cup S$.

Comment: Also as I commented above,  the notation is technically ambiguous but is  a very standard abuse of notation when the index set is obvious from context..   The author meant $\cup_{x\in \mathbb{N}}x$ and omitted the index set by abuse of notation

Comment: FShrike, thank you a lot for the answer. I do not understand the reasoning behind the notation, if it makes nothing, which is why I ask: are you that $\cup A = A$ for any set? I think I did not understand you answer; if so, sorry.

Comment: @Schilive $\cup A$ is not $A$, it’s a merging of the elements of $A$. If $A$ is a set of sets, e.g. $A=\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$, then $\cup A$ usually denotes, in my experience, $\{x,y,z\}$.

Comment: @FShrike, is it not the case that $\bigcup_{n \in A} \{n\} = A$ for any set $A$? or did  you want to say $\cup A = \bigcup_{n \in A} n$?

Comment: @Schilive In my experience of the notation, both sentences that you typed are true

Comment: @FShrike, then I believe you made a mistake on the text: you meant $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n$ instead of $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{n\}$. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Under the standard construction of natural numbers using sets, both statements are true, although the first is harder to understand @Schilive but in hindsight is maybe what Robert intended

Comment: In general $\bigcup_{x\in S}x\ne\bigcup_{x\in S}\{x\}$. The two are equal for $S=\Bbb N$ because of special properties of $\Bbb N$.